# How to stop the detection of a chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

Ethics aside, how could I run a chrome extension on a website without it being detected by that website?

Answer (score 1):

As long as you don't modify the DOM, don't respond to any message passing from the site, and don't make any extension assets web accessible, I'm not aware of any way for the site to tell. The JavaScript runs in a different context that the page doesn't have access to.